# Push/update array from JavaScript to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have made a array of data from Firebase, and want to display it on my website. It works fine one time, but when Firebase is updated, the website doesn´t update correspondingly. 
My goal is to make a list of updates. So when the database is updated, the new update is shown above the previous.

console.log(arr); logs every change made in the database, so basically I want what the console displays..

JS code:

```js
firebase.initializeApp(config);
  database = firebase.database();
  
  var ref = database.ref("users");
  ref.on("value", gotData, errData);
  
  function gotData(data) {
   // console.log(data.val);
   var users = data.val();
   var keys = Object.keys(users);
   //console.log(keys);
  
   for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var k = keys [i];
    var name = users [k].Name;
    var gender = users [k].Gender;
    var car = users [k].Car;
    var location = users [k].Location;
    var destination = users [k].Destination;
    
    
    // initialize array
var arr = [
    name,
    gender,
    car,
    location,
    destination,
];



// append new value to the array
arr.push(destination);

 document.getElementById('B1').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr);
console.log(arr);

 
   }
  }
  
  function errData(err) {
    console.log("Error");
    console.log(err);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html
<html>
    <head
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title>Test</title>
         <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.1/firebase.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Test
        <!-- Value -->
        <ol id="B1"></ol>
        
       <script src ="App.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Firebasestructure:

- App

  - users

    - 09IEbFijEnQpDita5DyhUdBE0eD3

      - Name: "Nick"
      - Car: "Audi"
      - Gender: " Male"
      - Location: "Home"
      - Destination: " Beach"

Is there a good (and hopefully not to complicated) way to reach my goal?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are resetting your array in every iteration, while you really want to keep the data from the previous iterations in there. So intitialise your array before entering the loop, and only add to it within the loop. In the same way you overwrite the output in the HTML element in each iteration. Instead, accumulate the data in the loop and only output the array after the loop:

```
function gotData(data) {
    var users = data.val();
    var keys = Object.keys(users);

    // initialize array here
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var k = keys[i];
        var name = users[k].Name;
        var gender = users[k].Gender;
        var car = users[k].Car;
        var location = users[k].Location;
        var destination = users[k].Destination;
        // append new value to the array
        arr.push([
            name,
            gender,
            car,
            location,
            destination,
        ]);
    }
    // And now output:
    document.getElementById('B1').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr);
    console.log(arr);
}
```

All this can be done a bit shorter with the use of `Object.values` (assuming you want all the data fields):

```
function gotData(data) {
    var arr = Object.values(data.val()).map(Object.values);
    document.getElementById('B1').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr);
    console.log(arr);
}
```

If you want the last value at the top of the output then use the `reverse` method, and if you want it in a list format then `map` the values to `li` tags. Finally, you may want to limit the number of rows to some constant (e.g. 10), which you can do with `slice`:

```
function gotData(data) {
    var arr = Object.values(data.val()).map(Object.values);
    B1.innerHTML = arr.slice(-10).reverse().map(val => `<li>${val}</li>`).join('');
}
```

Note that you don't really need `document.getElementById` nowadays, since browsers declare global variables for each of the elements with an `id` attribute. So you can just use the `B1` variable.

Comment: Great, that worked! Another question: Do you know if there´s a smart way to get the data in a list? It would be great if every time a user updated his or her location, the new data came on top of a list, pushing the previous down a notch? Thanks a lot for the help so far!

Comment: Thank you so much for you help! This is great! Do you know if it´s possible to make the new and/or updated posts to appear in a separate line? So that every time someone updates their profile, it would appear on top of the list? My goal is to have som kind of list, ordered or unordered, that constantly have the newest update at the top. Thank you very much for your help and patience so far, it s greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sure that would be possible. The above code already puts things in separate lines (as `li` tags do that by default). But in the information you have provided in the question I don't see any data element that determines the order of update. That would of course be needed to make the list sorted correctly, with the most recent at the top.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Is there a way to get to my goal with the current setup? Or do I have to reconfigure the whole thing? I can set each of the var´s to print in a separate innerHTML, but then I can´t get it to update every time someone updates their profile.

Comment: Just replace the whole, single `innerHTML` like you already did. I don't really understand what you want different. Without an actual example of what you get as input, and want to happen as output, it is hard to tell what you are after.

Comment: It would be great to have all the variables as separate innerHTML, but when I tried that it just updated one time. I couldn't get them to update when Firebase updates.